# Replace specific characters at specific positions in a string

Tags: sql, database

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. There is one column in the source table, `fiscal_week_string`, which is in the following format:

```
2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/31)
```

I want to convert this to the following format:

```
2011-01 (09/27 to 10/31)
```

I.e., I want to remove a *some* of the white spaces. I also want to replace the "`-`" inside the braces with "`to`".

Here's a few rows:

`datestr        pc      WEEK_START  WEEK_END    month_start mnth_end    year   mth  qtr wk  fiscal_week_string          Fiscal_month_string
2010-09-27  14879   2010-09-27  2010-10-03  2010-09-27  2010-10-31  2011    1   1   1   2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/03)   2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/31)
2010-09-28  14880   2010-09-27  2010-10-03  2010-09-27  2010-10-31  2011    1   1   1   2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/03)   2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/31)`

Could anyone please guide me with this?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You just want in select query or want to update in table?

Comment: @Luftwaffe Im using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @Sush I want to update the table.

Comment: Please provide a small repro: some DDL to create a sample table, along with some sample data. In addition, tell us what you've tried and researched so far. There are many ways to solve this, it'd help to know where you specifically got stuck (also: seeing the effort you've put in makes it more appealing for others to help out). GL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expecting the DDL as below since you have not shared it

```
create table table_one
(
fiscal_week_string varchar(30)
);

insert into table_one
values ('2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/31)');

insert into table_one
values ('2011 – 01 (09/26 – 11/31)');
```

your Oracle query would be

```
select col_one || col_two || col_three || ' ' || col_four||' '|| 'to'||' '||col_six as fmt_date
from
(
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) col_one,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) col_two,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 3) col_three,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 4) col_four,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 5) col_five,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.fiscal_week_string, '[^ ]+', 1, 6) col_six
from table_one t
)
```

and

results in

```
2011–01 (09/27 to 10/31) 
2011–01 (09/26 to 11/31)
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c30b15/8

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_replace to replace target patterns.

Example:

```
    select regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace('2011 - 01 (09/27 - 10/31)',' - ','-',1,1)
     , ' - ',' to ') from dual;
```

Sample update:

```
create table a1(id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into a1 values(1, '2011 - 01 (09/27 - 10/31)');
update a1 set name=
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(name,' - ','-',1,1), ' - ',' to ') where id=1;
select * from a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(50)='2011 – 01 (09/27 – 10/31)'

SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str, 0,CHARINDEX('(',@str)),' ','')+' '+ REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('(',@str),len(@str)),'–','to')
```